# アイコンへのバッジ表示について

Tags: javascript, android, monaca, iphone, html5

現在、Monacaを利用したスマホアプリ開発を行っており、アプリ内にある
一覧の未読件数をホーム画面のアイコンにバッジ表示させたいです。

ですが、アプリ内の画面ならわかりますがスマホのホーム画面のアイコンに
バッジ表示となると、どうやったらいいのか見当がつきません・・・

一応、LINEやメールでアイコンの右上に件数が出ているものがあるので
技術的に不可能ということは無いと思いますが・・・
また、アイコンバッジ表示はAndroid・iPhone両方に対応したいと思っています。

-追記-

Androidではバッジ表示は基本的に不可能ということですので一旦保留にしました。
引き続き、MonacaにてiPhone上でホームのアイコンにバッジ表示する方法を探しております。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Androidは基本できないはずです。

もし手元の端末でLineなどでバッチが表示されているとしたら、ホームアプリを別途利用しているのではないでしょうか？
例えば以下の様なアプリがあります。
[Androidのホームアプリ「GOランチャーEX」は無料で高性能！ でも、ひとつだけ難点が。](http://www.mayoinu.com/entry/2015/01/12/204133)

または、ウィジェットとして似たものを作ることが可能ですが、アプリアイコンとは別にユーザーの手動操作が必要になります。
[AndroidでGmailの通知バッジ（未読数）を付ける方法](http://sumaoji.com/gmail-tuti-badge-741)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
Androidでは前提としてできないのですね・・・
これがわかっただけでも大きく前進しました。

Answer (score 0):

ネイティブの機能にアクセスする必要があるのでcordovaプラグインを利用します。
下記のプラグインを使えば実現できそうです。Androidにも対応しています。

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge

ただし、カスタムcordovaプラグインを追加するにはmonacaの場合Goldプラン以上の有料プランに加入する必要があります。